# Pebble sdk 2.x unable to load resource

Tags: pebble-watch

I know pebble 2.x is a bit outdated, but that's the watch that I recently got and am interested in writing a small app on this.

I am unable to load the resource files (images and font) in my pebble app. Below is the error message when I try to run `pebble build`:

```
Setting top to                           : /home/mixi/Documents/pebble-dev/helloworld 
Setting out to                           : /home/mixi/Documents/pebble-dev/helloworld/build 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
Found Pebble SDK in          : /home/mixi/.pebble-sdk/SDKs/current/sdk-core/pebble/aplite
'configure' finished successfully (0.220s)
Waf: Entering directory `/home/mixi/Documents/pebble-dev/helloworld/build'
Error Generating Resources: File: bt-icon.png has specified invalid type: bitmap
Must be one of (raw, png, png-trans, font)
Generating resources failed
```

My `appinfo.json`:

```
{
  "uuid": "93c49fe2-0b1e-44b8-8fff-22d9c87adab9",
  "shortName": "helloworld",
  "longName": "helloworld",
  "companyName": "MakeAwesomeHappen",
  "versionLabel": "1.0",
  "sdkVersion": "2.9",
  "targetPlatforms": ["aplite", "basalt", "chalk"],
  "watchapp": {
    "watchface": true
  },
  "appKeys": {
    "dummy": 0
  },
  "resources": {
    "media": [
        {
          "type": "bitmap",
          "name": "IMAGE_BT_ICON",
          "file": "bt-icon.png"
        }
    ]
  },
  "versionCode": 1
}
```

My Pebble version:

```
Pebble Tool v4.0 (active SDK: v2.9)
```

I also tried creating a test app on pebblecloud with their sample. The sample runs fine without resource, but also fails when I add a new resource to the project. Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, pebble 2.x does not like "bitmap" type. All I had to do was change resource type to "png" in the JSON file:

```
"media": [
        {
          "type": "png",
          "name": "IMAGE_BT_ICON",
          "file": "bt-icon.png"
        }
    ]
```

OMG =A=..

As for CloudPebble, the drop down for Resource Type doesn't seem to show up and it seems to select Bitmap by default.. Maybe it'll be fixed in the near future idk.